# How to unzip multiple zip folders

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying to achieve one requirement that I have nested zip files there. I need to Unzip all those by single click. For that I have a code which is working only for one zipped folder and need to expand this. below is the code which I need to expand:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
function Unzip
{
param([string]$zipfile, [string]$outpath)
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipfile, $outpath)
}
Unzip "E:\Softwares\PS\AllFiles.zip" "E:\Softwares\PS\AllFiles"
```

Can any one suggest me a way to expand this to unzip the nested zip folders..

Comment: You'll have to get a list of the files in the zip file, and once you have that, just recursively invoke your `Unzip` function.

Comment: can you please bit elaborate this as I am new to this

Comment: You should really think about the problem more. The way *I* would do it would involve temporary directories to ensure that when I interrogate the file system to find the zip files that I've just extracted from another zip file, I'm not getting unrelated zip files. As far as actual code, not going to happen; this isn't a code-writing service. You need to try to work out an answer on your own, then come to us with _specific_ problems and what you don't understand/can't get working properly.

Comment: You should really look at [ask], and remember that around here we like it when you provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very detailed. I played with a little by having a file on C:\temp\ziptest that I placed multiple nested zip files in and this worked. Please note there could be a lot more variables that need to be accounted for (ie zip files have password, are they standard zip file or .7z, etc).

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
function Unzip
{
  param([string]$zipfile, [string]$outpath)
  [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipfile, $outpath)
}



$flag = $true
while($flag)
{
 $zipFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp\ziptest" -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*.zip"}

 if($zipFiles.count -eq 0)
 {
    $flag = $false
 }

 elseif($zipFiles.count -gt 0)
 {
    foreach($zipFile in $zipFiles)
    {
     #create the new name without .zip
     $newName = $zipFile.FullName.Replace(".zip", "")

     Unzip $zipFile.FullName $newName

     #remove zip file after unzipping so it doesn't repeat 
     Remove-Item $zipFile.FullName   
    }
 }
 Clear-Variable zipFiles
}
```

Comment: Hi this piece of code is working as expected. dis code only working in PS 5 version but it needs to work in PS V2.0. throwing error like Expand-Archive is not recognized                                                                  param [string]$source = C:\Files.zip",
 [string]$dest = "C:\Files"
 )
  $mainzip = gci -Path $source -Filter "*.zip"
 Expand-Archive -Path $mainzip.fullname -DestinationPath $dest
 $childzip = gci -Path $dest -Filter "*zip"
 foreach($childfile in $childzip){
 Expand-Archive -path $childfile.fullname -Destinationpath $dest
 }

Comment: No where am I using the expand-archive command in my code? I am using the same Unzip function you had above in question? Use the Unzip function above instead of expand-archive.

Comment: the above cod is not showing anything..means its not executing and not throwing any error also

Comment: My code or your code above? In mine you would have to change the -Path "C:\tem\ziptest" to your root path. That root path would have to be an unzipped folder to get started. You would need .net framework on the system for my above code to work.